# How to apply object detection?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, cnn, image-classification

I am struggling on object detection in an image, but not sure which model to use. I tried to design a model from scratch, *CNN*, but it could not meet my requirements. I need a right direction or step by step approach to help me achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multifarious studies about object detection. The method you are going to use depends on your data. For instance, if you have centre of the objects alongside their height and width, you can simply use *YOLO* method which is one of the pioneer approaches for detection. As another example, If you have data which is classified pixel-wise, you can employ *RCNN* methods or *Fully Convolutional* methods like *FCN* itself or *SegNet*. There are open source implementations with appropriate trained parameters for these models on GitHub.

Apart from the methods, you have to consider the restrictions they may exist for your conditions. For instance, there may be situations where your task is online and you have limited computational power. In such cases, I don't think you can employ very deep architectures like *SegNet*.

Comment: Thanks for your response, YOLO does not gives you the option to train your data from scratch. furthermore i want to play around with the cnn layers for improving the model for prediction.